# Termite: Remove Window decorations

Tags: arch-linux, xfwm4, termite

I could not find any documentation for termite's configuration, and looking at the config file in /etc/xdg/termite/config, I could not find any option to suit my needs. My question is, is it possible to remove/hide the titlebar/window-decorations in termite? I am using xfce4(xfwm4) on arch linux.